# Content for textarea will not fill when using volt syntax

Tags: phalcon, volt

Using the following code in my volt file, taken straight from the documentation (present here: http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/tags.html#helpers-to-generate-form-elements).

```
{{ text_area("comment", "This is the content", "cols": "6", "rows": 20) }}
```

It shows a textarea with correct name and id, correct column and rows but no content.

Comment: "This is the content" isnt displaying? Or are you trying to use content from the controller?

Comment: Neither content from the controller nor the string "This is the content" is displaying. Had to just build the textarea in html and put the content in with the standard volt variable syntax instead but would still like to know why this isn't working at all

Answer (score 2):

Only the first parameter is internally mapped to be the id.

All other parameters need a key.

This works:

{{ text_area("comment", "value":"This is the content", "cols": "6", "rows": 20) }}